# Web application that compiles to swf

Tags: actionscript-3, ant, compilation, flash

I have a swf template that can be used with different data input such as colors, texts etc. however i don't want to use the ordinary way of binding data to it such as xml. I would like the application to be able to produce a compiled swf with all the data in it.

Is it possible to inject the data in the compilation time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be, but depends on how much you want to mess around with the code of the template.

You can embed resources in flash, so you can just [embed the XML](http://flashgamedojo.com/wiki/index.php?title=Embedding_XML_in_AS3) with the information you want.

Then all you need to do if find the place in the code where it loads the XML file, and give it your own embedded XML file instead.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan, what are my options for trigering the compilation.?

Comment: you could use something like FlashDevelop which is completely free  - http://www.flashdevelop.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but only if you have access to the the source .fla file, so that you can generate a new .swf file from it.

If you simply want to change a few colors or other looks of some of the objects in the .fla file you should be able to do that without having to mess with xml, simply open the library items in Flash and edit their colors.

If you want to put your external assets within the actual .swf you can do that too, but if you already have it to pull external assets I would recommend keeping it that way.

For the XML, in ActionScirpt you can actually declare the XML within the actual Actionscript code. Open up the XML file and copy the the XML contents over to your code where it is parsing it.

For images you can simply drag image files directly on the stage or into the library.

Comment: I didn't mention itbut my users don't have flash ide installed they are working on a 'wizard' .